# Python function to find ALL second lowest SCORERS in a Dictionary with minimal possible order of time (O(n))

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, big-o

Hi I want to write a python function to find all lowest scorers in dictionary with time complexity of o(n).

The function should handle 2nd lowest value in any index of dictionary including the first k,v pairs.

function should handle duplicate lowest scores too.

**Testcase:**

> second_lowest_scorers({"hri":6.2,"dav":1.1,"asv":1.1,"wrs":12.3,"dup":6.2,"awe":43.2,"asw":22.2,"asd":6.2})

**expected output:**

> ['asd', 'dup', 'hri'] **(optional: sorted by name)**

**Explanation** asv and dav scored 1.1 which is lowest score. asd,dup,hri scored next lowest.

I have so far solved it using multiple loops.

```
def lowest_scores(names_scores):

    lowest_score=min(names_scores.values())
    
    lowscorers=[]

    low_scorer_dict = { k : v for k,v in names_scores.items() if v != lowest_score}
    
    second_lowest_score = min(low_scorer_dict.values())

    for k,v in low_scorer_dict.items():
        if v == second_lowest_score:
            lowscorers.append(k)
        
    return sorted(lowscorers)
```

Dont want to use external functions like to solve algorithmic way possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O(N) solution

```
data = {"hri":6.2,"dav":1.1,"asv":1.1,"wrs":12.3,"dup":6.2,"awe":43.2,"asw":22.2,"asd":6.2}

vals = set(data.values()) # create set so we don't get duplicates
vals.remove(min(vals)) # remove the most minimum
minVal = min(vals) # this is the second minimum

for k,v in data.items():
    if v == minVal :
        print(k) # where value is second minimum
```

```
hri
dup
asd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. how is function min(n) is eliminated on the time complexity? Sorry I am still learning

Comment: @user2382280 I am glad it helped, if your query is resolved please mark it as an answer! so finding min is O(N)  and removing it from the set is O(1)